# Why is there an error when i use openssl with -iter option?

Tags: encryption, terminal, openssl, des

I am using openssl to decrypt a DES-ECB cipher, but when i use

`openssl enc -d -des-ecb -in com2.enc -base64 -out com2.txt -pass pass:password -iter 256`

it gives an error and shows the help section. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of OpenSSL are you using (what is the output from `openssl version`)?

Comment: It just shows LibreSSL 2.6.5

Comment: Never mind. This worked for me ```echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc```